# oracle forms 12. how to display leading zero of decimal numbers

Tags: oracle, decimal, oracleforms

I wish to display decimal numbers (from a query) into text items.
if I set

`:TXT_ITEM := '0,000123456789'`

it works. But, if `:TXT_ITEM` is bound to a numeric table field, value is displayed as `,000123456789`.

I'm trying to force format number on several triggers (post-change, when-new-record-instance, post-text...), unsuccessfully. On other hand, setting format_mask would force my DB value to a given number of decimal digits.

How can I get leading zero to be displayed?

Comment: When you say "setting format_mask", do you mean setting it in the field properties, or setting it via code as described earlier in your post?

Answer (score 0):

See if any of these two options help.

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    (select 12.34 col             from dual union all
  3     select 0.1234003             from dual union all
  4     select -13.43432203          from dual union all
  5     select 0.00012345221         from dual union all
  6     select -0.002412428238234821 from dual
  7    );

Table created.

SQL> desc test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL                                                NUMBER

SQL> select col,
  2    regexp_replace(col, '^(-?)([.,])', '\10\2') result1,
  3    rtrim(to_char(col, 'fm90D999999999999999999999'), '.') result2
  4  from test;

       COL RESULT1                   RESULT2
---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
     12,34 12,34                     12,34
  ,1234003 0,1234003                 0,1234003
-13,434322 -13,43432203              -13,43432203
,000123452 0,00012345221             0,00012345221
-,00241243 -0,002412428238234821     -0,002412428238234821

SQL>
```

How would use it/them in Forms? Exactly like that - you'd e.g.

```
select regexp_replace(col, '^(-?)([.,])', '\10\2')
  into :block.text_item
  from your_table
  where some_condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the concerned numeric data in the table is of type

```
NUMBER(13,12)
```

in this case it's enough to set `TXT_ITEM`s `Format Mask` attribute within the `Data` part of `Property Palette` as

```
0D000000000000
```

with precision of `13` and scale of `12` values.

Considering the scale part is fixed, you can add more zeroes before `D` character depending on your column's precision value such as two zeroes before `D` are kept for `NUMBER(14,12)` or three zeroes for `NUMBER(15,12)`.